# Very simple Fortran code produces error when compiled with gfortran + fpe trap flags

Tags: fortran, gfortran

The following simple code:

```
program small_test
double precision :: a, b, c, d 
open(5,file='infile.dat',status='old')
READ (5,*) a, b, c, d
print *, a, b, c, d
end program
```

works just fine when I compile with gfortran, no trap flags:

```
$> gfortran  small_test.f90
```

The input data is

```
0.087266463 0.087266463   3. 100.
```

and the output is

```
   8.7266463000000002E-002   8.7266463000000002E-002   3.0000000000000000        100.00000000000000
```

as expected.

But when I compile to trap floating point errors,

```
gfortran -ffpe-trap=invalid,zero,overflow,underflow,precision,denormal -fdump-core small_test.f90
```

the code fails with error

```
Program received signal SIGFPE: Floating-point exception - erroneous arithmetic operation.
```

How could this simple code possibly produce an error?

(What's really going on is that I am debugging a much larger code and I need the traps to find some problem somewhere else in the code.  But I need to get past this trivial input statement, where they are tripping me up somehow.)

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark   Typo.  Fixed it.

Comment: EOL.  It is a linux file, not DOS, if that is what you are wondering about.

Comment: The error occurs in the `READ` statement, and the relevant flag is `-ffpe-trap=precision`.  Perhaps it is something to do with the conversion of the text representation of the numbers to the internal floating point representation.

Comment: The error also occurs with `-ffpe-trap=inexact`. Maybe `precision` is an alias for `inexact`; I don't see `precision` in https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Debugging-Options.html#Debugging-Options.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser   Agree.  Thanks.  This is a surprise to me.  I have tried fixing it with formatted input using a "D" descriptor, but it doesn't help.  If you want to turn your comment into an answer, I will accept it.  And of course, if you have ideas about how to fix this, that would be even better!

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42098438/floating-point-exception-when-reading-real-values-from-an-input-file

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser  `precision` is discussed in the gfortran man page.  Don't know why it wouldn't be in the on line docs.

Comment: *"If you want to turn your comment into an answer, I will accept it."*  Do you agree that the question that I linked to is close enough to yours that this question can be considered a duplicate?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser  Yes, I think so.

Comment: OK then, I will connect them.

Comment: The old answer does not actually show how to use modern Fortran facilities to manipulate the floating exceptions.

Comment: @Steve, it would be better to add an answer to that other question.

Comment: @bob.sacamento: precision is a (deprecated) alias for inexact. Thus it has been removed from the manual, but it's till accepted for backwards compatibility. The online manual you linked to is to the latest development version, whereas your man page presumably corresponds to the version of gfortran you have installed. If you gfortran is old enough, the man page still mentions precision.

Comment: @janneb  Thanks for the information!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really think that you want to enable floating-point traps on ieee_inexact, then you should probably use the facilities provided by the Fortran language to control the exception instead of a compiler option.  Try

```
program small_test
   use ieee_arithmetic
   implicit none
   double precision :: a, b, c, d
   logical flag
   open(5,file='infile.dat',status='old')
   if (ieee_support_flag(ieee_inexact)) then
      call ieee_get_halting_mode(ieee_inexact, flag)
      call ieee_set_halting_mode(ieee_inexact, .false.)
   end if
   read (5,*) a, b, c, d
   print *, a, b, c, d
   if (ieee_support_flag(ieee_inexact)) then
      call ieee_set_halting_mode(ieee_inexact, flag)
   end if
end program
```